# Rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Studying for a course in fields, and came across the question: is the field $\mathbb{C}(x)$ of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$ algebraically closed?

At the moment I think it is, as I can't seem to find a simple counter-example nor a good reason as to why it shouldn't be, but it seems as though I may be missing a trick here, and my initial thought was to be suspicious of how simple it seems. Any hints or help greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn’t have an element $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2=x$

Comment: To use J.W. Tanner's hint assume a solution $\alpha=p(x)/q(x)$ exists. Expand, clear the denominators, and look at the degrees of the polynomials on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Ah okay, of course - that seems so obvious now! Thanks for that.

Comment: Feel free to write it up as an answer! That way you get more feedback on the details. We do need to check whether this question has been asked earlier.

Comment: For sure - thanks for the help. I've posted my attempt at making the solution rigorous, any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to both J.W. Tanner and Jyrki Lahtonen for their help with this question - here's my attempt at making the solution rigorous.

Suppose the field $\mathbb{C}(x)$ of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. Take the polynomial $P(y) = y^2 - x$; then since $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is algebraically closed, $P$ must have a root in $\mathbb{C}(x)$. But $P(y)=0$ if and only if $y^2 = x$, for some $y \in \mathbb{C}(x)$. Suppose that $y = p(x)/q(x)$. Then we have that:
$$
\frac{p^2(x)}{q^2(x)} = x \implies p^2(x) = xq^2(x)
$$
Hence considering degrees, we see that we must have $2\text{deg}(p) = 1+2\text{deg}(q)$, and so $2(\text{deg}(p) - \text{deg}(q))=1 \implies \text{deg}(p) - \text{deg}(q) = 1/2$, a contradiction as $p,q$ are polynomials. Thus no such $y$ exists, i.e. $P$ has no root in $\mathbb{C}(x)$ and hence $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: This a correct answer, but it could be said a lot more concisely - the point is that $x$ has no square roots because of degrees. The paragraph preceding the equation introduces a contradiction you don't need - better to start by declaring that you'll show $y^2-x$ lacks a root and then using contradiction on that more specific statement. Then, once you reach $2\deg(p)=1+2\deg(q)$, you might as well stop - it's clear enough that this can't happen and the further algebra distracts from the point. Having shown a polynomial with no root, you can conclude $\mathbb C(x)$ is not algebraically closed.