# Algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

What is the algebraic closure of the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$ in variable $t$? Is it true that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(t)}=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$?

Comment: What is a solution to $X^2-t=0$?

Comment: I'm slightly rusty on this particular topic, but maybe check out something called "model theory", and how it relates to algebraic closures.

Comment: $\alpha\beta\gamma$, compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330895/rational-functions-over-mathbbc-is-algebraically-closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We definitely have that $\overline{\Bbb Q}(t)\subseteq \overline{\Bbb Q(t)}$, but the other inclusion is not true. For example, in $\overline{\Bbb Q}(t)$, there is no solution to the equation $X^2-t=0$.

Comment: I got confused with notations. What are the differences between $\overline{\Bbb Q}(t) $ and $\overline{\Bbb Q(t)}$

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb Q}(t)$ is the field of rational functions of $t$ with *coefficients* in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. On the other hand, $\overline{\mathbb Q(t)}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$, so it contains functions like $\sqrt{t}$ or $\sqrt[3]{t/(t^2-1)}-7$.

Comment: Kenta, thank you for your explanation. I have a post related to this topic. Here is the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4407133/707884. Do you have an idea?