# Extended of algebraically independent set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, transcendence-degree

Let $T$ be a transcendental basis of $\Bbb R$ and $A\subset T.$ For $B\subset\Bbb R$, by $\overline{\Bbb Q}(B)$ the sets of all $x\in\Bbb R$ that are algebraic over $\Bbb Q(B).$

Now, let $S\subset\Bbb R$, $S$ is not algebraically independent, and $S$ is a countable set such that $$\overline{\Bbb Q}(A\cup S)=\Bbb R$$

Notice that $A\cup S$ is not algebraically independent. So, I can not say $A\cup S$ is a transcendental basis. But we also know each algebraically independent set can be extended to a transcendental basis, using Zorn's lemma. Then, there exists an algebraically independent set, say $G$,  such that $A\cup G$ is a transcendental basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q.$ Here is my question

> $G$ will be a countable set. Is that right?

I think it is. Any idea.

Comment: @egreg. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your notation seems nonstandard. The set of all $x\in\mathbb R$ that are algebraic over $\mathbb Q(B)$ should be denoted $\overline{\mathbb Q(B)}\cap\mathbb R$.

Comment: @KentaS, thank you for your comment. I did not find any reference that uses this notation so this is why I did it like that.  Could you refer me to a book or paper, note that uses this notation?

Comment: It is standard notation in the literature; basically any textbook should use it. For a field $k$, its algebraic closure, i.e., the set of elements algebraic over $k$, is denoted $\overline k$. You hope to denote all elements which are algebraic over $\mathbb Q(B)$, i.e., elements of $\overline{\mathbb Q(B)}$, which also happen to be real. This is exactly the intersection $\overline{\mathbb Q(B)}\cap\mathbb R$.

Comment: @KentaS, Thank you for your explanation. I do not  see  it in some textbooks like Algebra by Hungerford and Basic Algebra II by N A T H A N J A C O B S ON . Thank you again

Comment: Wait how do *you* use the notation $\overline k$ then?

Comment: @KentaS, I just made it up

Comment: Making notation should be avoided when it has a pre-existing meaning in the literature.

Comment: @KentaS, I agree. But I did not find any using this notation. I have posted on this site, I do not remember when about algebraic closure and no told thing. However, If you can give a book name or literature that uses this notation, it would be a great help .

Comment: Wolfram MathWorld, Stacks project, nLab, n-category Cafe, Lang Algebra VII section 2 (page 172), Atiyah-Macdonald Exercise 1.13 (page 12), Silverman Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves (page 1), Vakil 19.7.1 (page 519), ...

Comment: @KentaS. Thank you for your comment. I appreciate